# MYSQL - Get all months between two dates (from, to) and data for this months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table something like that:

```
| id       | date        | user_id  | value |
---------------------------------------------
| 1        | 2019-01-10  |   3      | 20
| 2        | 2019-04-08  |   3      | 30
| 3        | 2019-06-04  |   3      | 40
| 4        | 2019-08-20  |   3      | 50 
| 5        | 2019-11-19  |   3      | 60
| 6        | 2019-01-11  |   4      | 70
| 7        | 2019-02-20  |   4      | 11
| 8        | 2019-03-11  |   4      | 12
| 9        | 2019-07-12  |   4      | 23
--------------------------------
```

and I want to get values between two dates: date_from and date_to. And all months from this interval.

For example:

date_from = 2019-01-08;
date_to = 2019-09-10;

So for user_id = 3 i want to get something like that:

```
   | date     | value
    -------------------------
   | 2019-01  |   20      |
   | 2019-02  |   NULL    |
   | 2019-03  |   NULL    |
   | 2019-04  |   30      |
   | 2019-05  |   NULL    |
   | 2019-06  |   40      |
   | 2019-07  |   NULL    |
   | 2019-08  |   50      |
   | 2019-09  |   NULL    |
    --------------------------
```

Is anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It seems quite odd that your results are by month but you time period is in days.

Comment: can there be more than one entry for a user in one month?  if yes, are tha value to be added?

Comment: @Turo No, it can't.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it just because i need it to charts, so i need only year and month without day.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (e.g. missing values) in application code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates and then `left join`:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2019-01-08') as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where dte < '2019-09-10'
     )
select extract(year_month from d.dte) as yyyymm, sum(t.value)
from dates d left join
     t
     on d.dte = t.date and t.user_id = 3
group by yyyymm;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1acd1f2ef9ab906c8635e95630131618) is a db<>fiddle.